# Why is the C++ scope resolution operator ::?

Tags: c++

This is one of the few questions I didn't find an answer to in Design and Evolution of C++ by Stroustroup.  Why is the C++ scope resolution operator ::, as opposed to just :?

I'm guessing it's because : is already used to indicate the start of an initialization list in a constructor.  Does anyone else agree, disagree, or have a definitive answer on this?

Comment: Well there is usually a reason, language design is not usually totally arbitrary.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It would create an ambiguity with `goto` labels, for one.

```
foo:bar;  // is foo a label or a namespace?
```

Comment: Nice one, didn't think about that because of course hardly anybody uses gotos.